# Why "part of" instead of "a part of"?

Tags: grammar

I feel like *part* is a countable so we have either use it in the singular form *a part* or *the part* or in the plural form *part*. However, I see most of the times it is used with no article in the singular form *part*. 
How is that possible and why do the English treat this word as such?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["As part of" versus "as a part of"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/as-part-of-versus-as-a-part-of) Also [Difference between 'part' and 'a part'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158232/), where [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/158235/2637) looks good to me.

Comment: The [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/part) says that *part* can be either countable or uncountable.

Comment: I don't think that your simple school rule about article + countable noun covers all cases where English drops the article. I would recommend collecting all cases that are not conform with your school rule to get  a feeling that a school rule is a school rule. Please remember the more often a formula is used the faster it is shortened.